# Sorting and boosting

Tags: solr

Is it possible to sorting a boosting query in Solr? 
I have the following situation:

```
<doc id="A">>
   <str name="PUB_DATE">2017-04-19T11:08:30Z</str>
   <str name="TIPOLOGY">TWO</str>
</doc>
<doc id="B">
   <str name="PUB_DATE">2017-04-19T11:08:30Z</str>
   <str name="TIPOLOGY">ONE</str>
</doc>
<doc id="C">
   <str name="PUB_DATE">2017-04-19T11:08:30Z</str>
   <str name="TIPOLOGY">THREE</str>
</doc>
<doc id="D">
   <str name="PUB_DATE">2017-04-20T11:08:30Z</str>
   <str name="TIPOLOGY">ONE</str>
</doc>
```

the idea is:

- first of all sort by pub_date desc.
- In case of same pub_date, boosting by tipology field. One, two, three.

So by the above example, Solr query will be return D --> B --> A --> C

I try the following query but doesn't work:

```
/select?defType=edismax&q=XXXXXXXX&sort=PUB_DATE+desc&bq=TIPOLOGY:ONE^100+TIPOLOGY:B^10++TIPOLOGY:C^1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your 'sort' param is asking the results to be sorted only by PUB_DATE, and bq param is affecting the score of each doc.

What you need to do is ask them to be sorted by PUB_DATE first, and then score, like this:

```
/select?defType=edismax&q=XXXXXXXX&sort=PUB_DATE desc, score desc&bq=TIPOLOGY:ONE^100+TIPOLOGY:B^10++TIPOLOGY:C^1
```

If your bq boosts are enough to get the docs' scores in order it would work (as the score is also influenced by the q=XXXXXX part)